# 2sxc: Permissions by Field

Tags: 2sxc

In 2sxc for DNN, is it possible to set visibility or edit permissions by the field rather than the entity type or template? I'm imagining a case where I want a public form where the submitter can add "Issue" and "Description", but then a staff member can see those fields as well as "Status" - or something like that.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not by itself configurable, but it can be done in a different way.

Usually the public side would be a custom form using jQuery or angular, and it would be optimized to that use case, with much more customized look & feel. Then save using the normal REST API or a custom WebApi.

The backend user can then either have a custom form (more work but more perfect) or just use the standard, which shows him/her all fields.

Comment: Good to know - thanks! I would think field permissions would be a cool addition. I'd imagine it would go well with allowing default values applying to invisible fields. I'm not sure how this would work, and the mechanics of it connecting with various views gets messy... But it would open some doors.